# Hibernate/Postgresql batch insert no longer working after upgrade

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I recently upgraded from Spring Boot 2.4.x to 2.6.x, which included an update of Hibernate from 5.1.2 to 5.6.3.  After the update, the INSERTs are no longer batched (I can tell because the execution time is much faster before the update.)

I didn't see anything in the Hibernate release notes that seemed relevant.

Any idea what the fix might be?

My configuration:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://myurl?reWriteBatchedInserts=true
 jpa:
   properties:
     hibernate:
       dialect:  org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
       jdbc:
         batch_size: 50
         order_inserts: true
```

The entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence-generator")
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "sequence-generator",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
        parameters = {
                @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "my_id_seq"),
                @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
                @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "50")
        }
)
private Integer id;
```

Postgresql driver:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: How do you know that the batch mode no longer works? Have you activated the traces on the statistics?

Comment: I have experienced the same issue! Was using hibernate-core:5.4.5.Final when one day I said: time to upgrade stuff. So I went to hibernate-core:5.6.7.Final and afterwards noticed everything being much slower. After painful analysis I realized that batching stopped working (verified via logging). I can also tell you that the break happens at version 5.6.1-Final, whereas 5.6.0-Final is working fine. Don't know why that happens though

Answer (score 0):

Based on the below posts, it seems this issue had been reported and fixed recently:

https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/inserts-updates-no-longer-executed-as-jdbc-batch-statements/6337
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15281

However, I resolved it by simply downgrading the `hibernate-core` library back to the original version (5.3.9.Final in my case). Was able to keep the other spring library versions unchanged.